# Unable to Deploy Flatcar OS on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-vm, vhd, azure-linux

I was trying to deploy flatcar image on Azure, but I am not able to deploy it. following are the steps I performed

1. I downloaded latest azure supported VHD from https://stable.release.flatcar-linux.net/amd64-usr/current/flatcar_production_azure_image.vhd.bz2.
2. I uploaded this VHD to azure storage blob and converted it to an image as recommended by Azure guides
3. I tried creating VM out of this image. VM gets created successfully, but we can see one error while creating VM and VM creation is shown as failed (Even though it is actually successful). Following is the error which I can see:

```
{
  "code": "DeploymentFailed",
  "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.",
  "details": [
    {
      "code": "VMExtensionHandlerNonTransientError",
      "message": "The handler for VM extension type 'Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics.LinuxDiagnostic' has reported terminal failure for VM extension 'LinuxDiagnostic' with error message: '[ExtensionOperationError] Non-zero exit code: 1, /var/lib/waagent/Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics.LinuxDiagnostic-3.0.141/diagnostic.py -install\n[stdout]\n\n\n[stderr]\n  File \"/var/lib/waagent/Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics.LinuxDiagnostic-3.0.141/diagnostic.py\", line 54\n    print 'A local import (e.g., waagent) failed. Exception: {0}\\n' \\\n          ^\nSyntaxError: invalid syntax\n'.\r\n    \r\n'Install handler failed for the extension. More information on troubleshooting is available at https://aka.ms/VMExtensionLinuxDiagnosticsTroubleshoot'"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried going through link provided, but it didn't help much.
I also tried another option as following

1. Deployed flatcar VM through Azure marketplace
2. Captured generalized image out of this VM
3. Deployed VM using the image created in above step

Even with this approach I am getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

for now, waagent (Azure Linux agent) does not support python 3.x, hence this syntax error exists. You need to have python 2.x on your OS to not have this issue.